# How to make a linked list out of a matrix?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a small matrix with 3x3 dimension

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Let's call it matrix[l][c] where l is for lines, and c for columns.
I have this struct defined:

```
typedef struct cell{
    int *neighbours[4];
    int flag;
    char value;
}NODE
```

I want to do a linked list based on the matrix. Neighbours would have to have the adress of the neighbours of that cell(up, down, right,left), flag it's defined 0 for all at first, and value is just the letter the cell has.

How would i build this linked list to store the info for all the cells in the matrix? I must tell i have very little experience with linked lists. Never worked with them

Thank you

Comment: That's not really a linked-list.

Comment: what is your data stored in right now? I mean, the 3x3 matrix - is it an array, or do you need to read it from file and put into the new data structure on the fly?

Comment: Hi @Pavel. Matrix is stored on a char matrix[][]. I think it's the same as a double pointer. Like char **matrix. You would acess it the same way as matrix [line][collum]. And yes, i read it from a file and load it to that 2D array.

Comment: so you just need to loop through the matrix, create instances of your struct and set the members accordingly. have you tried something? btw, why is `neighbors` an `int*`? what do you want to store there? in order to link elements, you need to point to neighboring elements, so I guess you need `cell*`.

Comment: i want to store the adress of the neighbours. So say that i am on the A cell, and i want to go to the D. I have the pointer there. Yeah i guess you are right. As i told you, i don't have any experience with linked lists yet :P

Answer (score 1):

```
struct cell{
    struct cell *nesw[4];
    int flag;
    char value;
} cells[9] =
{ { { NULL   , cells+1, cells+3, NULL   }, 0, 'a' }
, { { NULL   , cells+2, cells+4, cells  }, 1, 'b' }
, { { NULL   , NULL   , cells+5, cells+1}, 2, 'c' }

, { { cells  , cells+4, cells+6, NULL   }, 3, 'd' }
, { { cells+1, cells+5, cells+7, cells+3}, 4, 'e' }
, { { cells+2, NULL   , cells+8, cells+4}, 5, 'f' }

, { { cells+3, cells+7, NULL   , NULL   }, 6, 'g' }
, { { cells+4, cells+8, NULL   , cells+6}, 7, 'h' }
, { { cells+5, NULL   , NULL   , cells+7}, 8, 'i' }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store each of the cells as nodes of the linked-list.

```
struct LinkedListNode;

typedef struct cell{
    struct LinkedListNode* neighbours[4];
    int flag;
    char value;
}NODE;

struct LinkedListNode {
    NODE data;
    struct LinkedListNode* next;
};
```

Each node will contain one cell. And `neighbours[i]` will point to the corresponding adjacent cell. So basically, if you form a linked-list of the cells, the whole structure will look like an adjacency list.

Comment: Hi Rikayn, thank you. But how do i build it based on my matrix now? Like how would i acess for example the cell stored in matrix [1][1] that corresponds to E?

Comment: If for example, your first node corresponds to `[0][0]`, then do `neighbours[DOWN]` and `neighbours[RIGHT]` consecutively to reach to the `[1][1]` node.

Comment: Shure i get that, but where is the fist element stored? My problem is not defining the structure. Is building it based on the matrix :)

Comment: Loop over your matrix elements to build the structure. Once you find the proper node, link it to the corresponding `neighbour`.

Comment: Hmm, ok so let's imagine this. I build a NODE for each cell on the matrix using two for loops right? for bla bla bla, function that builds NODE, and all is build. How do i know what's the first NODE i build?

Comment: You an choose any node to be the first node. You can also insert two `int`s in `NODE` -  `xPos` and `yPos`, to indicate their positions.

Comment: Ok i guess you don't understand what is my difficulty xD Imagine i do a function that receives a position of a matrix, and returns a NODE. I apply that function to all cells in the matrix using two for loops. ok i get that, and i know have 9 NODE. But how do i store the position of the first node? The node on [0][0]? How and where do i store it to use it on the next steps i need to do?